# Function to get foreign key and store it to another table with php and postgresql

Tags: php, function, postgresql

I have two tables (users, photos) in my postgres database. The first keeps information about users and the second about images they upload. I have the following code where i'm trying to store user's id (field id) into photos (field user_id). Html code calls function upload() for uploading photos. Everything seems to work fine apart from the functions that returns the id variable. Function cleanMemberSession is called when user logs in and accepts post values from login form.

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$_SESSION["login"];
$_SESSION["password"];
$_SESSION["loggedIn"];
$link;
$login;
$dbname='db';                                                               
$user='postgres';                                                           
$host='localhost';                                                          
$password='password';                                                   

function connectToDB($dbname)
{
    global $link, $host, $user, $password, $login;

    $constr = "dbname=$dbname user=$user host=$host password=$password";
    $login = $_SESSION["login"];
    $link = pg_connect($constr);
    return $link;
    if  ($link)
    {   
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No connection<br>";
    }
} 

function cleanMemberSession($login, $password) 
{
    $_SESSION["login"]=$login;
    $_SESSION["password"]=$password;
    $_SESSION["loggedIn"]=true;

}

function user_id()
{   
    global $link; 
    $login = $_SESSION["login"];
    $sql="SELECT id FROM users WHERE login = '".$login."'";
    $result=pg_query($link, $sql);
    $row=pg_fetch_row($result);
    return $row[0];

}

function upload()
{   
    $conn = connectToDB('db');
    $image_name = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
    $upload_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $datestamp = date("Ymd", strtotime(date("Y-m-d")));
    $userid = user_id();

     $query = "INSERT INTO images (image_name, upload_time, user_id) VALUES 
     ('$image_name', '$upload_time', '$userid')";
     $result = pg_query($query);  
}
?>
```

Comment: The error seems to be the value that function user_id returns resulting in no data inserted into database. For example when i insert a value on my own for user_id => $query = "INSERT INTO ugc (image_name, upload_time, user_id) VALUES ('$image_name', '$upload_time', '1')" the query works fine.

Comment: Have you tried to print value variable inside user_id function to check if value is correctly passed to the function?

Comment: I tried that but nothing appears on the screen

Comment: Then it seems that there is a problem when you send the value to the function

Comment: Variable link should be at $result=pg_query($link, $sql); right? Or it could be just $result=pg_query($sql);

Comment: if you do a `var_dump($value);die();` inside user_id function and the $value hasn´t any data then you are sending the $value in a bad way. you should post the code where you send data too

Comment: I edited code above. If someone could help i would appreciate it.

Comment: Put this code `function user_id()
{   
    global $link; 
    $login = $_SESSION["login"];
    echo "login: ".$login;die();
    $sql="SELECT id FROM users WHERE login = '".$login."'";
    $result=pg_query($link, $sql);
    $row=pg_fetch_row($result);
    return $row[0];

}`
And show me the output.

Answer (score 0):

write $login out of functions!

```
$link;
$login;
$dbname='db';
$user='postgres';
$host='localhost';
$password='password';
```

Comment: If you do a while inside a function userID can you see something :`   while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "UserId: $row[0]";
    echo "<br />\n";}
` and to remove $row=pg_fetch_row($result);
    return $row[0];

Comment: Try this:if ($result)
{
    while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result))
        return $row[0];
} To make a full control make a print to a $result.

Comment: I can't see anything. I think it's what value i assign to login. I'll check this out and i'll come back later

Comment: Make a echo to a value and see what is? Is the same in your DB?